# Creating a custom list based off of a task list

Tags: 2010, list

I have created a content type MyTask that is built ontop of task. The content type ID starts with `0x0108`.

I want to create a custom list definition for my task in code. So I have created a List difention based on  my content type in Visual Studio.

I am then using this custom MyTask list in a workflow. However when I deploy my code I am getting the error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The
>   BaseTemplate property of the list is not 'Tasks'.

Looking at my Elements.xml for the list it looks like I should change the base type.

However when searching for the options of base type I can only seem to find:

```
Custom List 0
Document Library 1
Not used 2 
Obsolete. Use 0 for discussion boards.3 
Surveys 4
Issues List 5
```

How can I use my custom list with a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following attribute in 'ListTemplate' Type=107 
for example

```
  <ListTemplate
      Name="NameOfYourListDefinition"
      Type="107"
      BaseType="0" />
```

This will resolve your problem.